# Is there a way to call c code from a substrate project?

Tags: substrate

It's trivial to call c from rust normally, is there a way to do so from a substrate project? I can't find anything online saying it's possible or it's not possible.

I have a c library I'd like to use as part of a substrate project and I was wondering if it would be possible to use it without rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many FFI libraries are `no_std` compliant, this is the only hard requirement for being used in substrate **runtimes**. Checkout the list here and look for that tag for options to move forward:
https://lib.rs/development-tools/ffi

If you are using this library *outside* the runtime, you should be able to use any rust library.